# an error in sending json data to flask server

Tags: python, rest, dictionary, flask

I have a json data as

```
{"age":59.0,"bp":70.0,"sg":1.01,"al":3.0,"su":0.0,"rbc":1.0,"ba":0.0,"bgr":76.0,"bu":186.0,"sc":15.0,"sod":135.0,"pot":7.6,"hemo":7.1,"pcv":22.0,"wbcc":3800.0,"rbcc":2.1,"htn":1.0,"dm":0.0,"cad":0.0,"appet":0.0,"pe":1.0,"ane":1.0}
```

I have to send this json into a ML model that is inside a flask server to predict outcome class as 0 or 1.

so for that I wrote the following code in `app.py`

```
# flask route for ml model
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import keras
import ast

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_raw = request.get_json()
        print(data_raw)
        #convert json to dict
        new_dict = ast.literal_eval(data_raw)
        # initialize a new list to store the dict values
        data=[]
        for i in new_dict.values():
            data.append(i)
        # converted the values list to np array and reshaped it
        data = np.array(data)
        data = np.array(data.reshape(1, -1))
        print(data)
        # load model
        model = keras.models.load_model('model.pkl', 'rb')
        # make prediction
        prediction = model.predict(data)
        print(prediction)
        return jsonify({'prediction': prediction.tolist()})
    else:
        return jsonify({'prediction': 'error'})

# run flask app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But on sending that json as POST request to `localhost:5000/predict` I am getting an error as

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: {'age': 59.0, 'bp': 70.0, 'sg': 1.01, 'al': 3.0, 'su': 0.0, 'rbc': 1.0, 'ba': 0.0, 'bgr': 76.0, 'bu': 186.0, 'sc': 15.0, 'sod': 135.0, 'pot': 7.6, 'hemo': 7.1, 'pcv': 22.0, 'wbcc': 3800.0, 'rbcc': 2.1, 'htn': 1.0, 'dm': 0.0, 'cad': 0.0, 'appet': 0.0, 'pe': 1.0, 'ane': 1.0}
```

Though the same `data` preprocessing part of pushing the dict in the `model.predict` is working in the training code, but its creating an error here.

[model url for use in reconstruction of code](https://github.com/Samar-080301/ckd)

Comment: Have you considered using `json.loads()` instead of `ast.literal_eval()`?

Comment: Note, you can simplify your code a lot by doing `data = np.array(dict_you_get_from_json.values())`

Comment: Can you please share the result of printing `data_raw`?

Comment: it's not working

Comment: ...what's not working?

Comment: `json.loads()` is not working

Comment: I have sent you the code and the model, can you please check in your pc? if possible? Because I am getting the same error every time and its my first time in flask :-(

Comment: No, sorry. I've made a simple request. What is printed by the statement `print(data_raw)`?

Comment: The error is caused by attempting to use `ast.literal_eval()` on something that is not a valid string representation of a literal Python object. Therefore you need to inspect what's being passed to `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: If you need to, wrap the `ast.literal_eval()` call in a `try` block and catch the `ValueError`.

Comment: but the function is not print the data or the datatype, it's just sending the response to the post request, i tried printing it. But it didn't worked, I am getting the raw data from a post request

Comment: You don't see the result of `print(data_raw)` in the terminal you used to start the app?

Comment: No i am not getting the value of it

Comment: Okay well I am... and `data_raw` already is a dict. Flask seems to automatically converting the json to a Python object.

Comment: Okay! So should i directly fetch the values of the dict?

Comment: You should share the whole traceback, it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.get_json()` method is already doing the work of converting your JSON to a Python object. You can already use `data_raw` as a dictionary:

```py
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_raw = request.get_json()
        print(type(data_raw))  # prints 'dict' in the terminal used to start the server
        data = np.array(data_raw.values()).reshape(1, -1)
        # do model stuff
```

The error you were getting is because `ast.literal_eval()` expects a valid string representation of a literal Python object. By passing what you didn't realize was already a `dict` object, Python complained that the input was malformed.

By the way, in general when working with JSON in other contexts, you should be using `json.loads(some_json_string)` and `json.dumps(some_python_object_you_want_to_serialize)`. The `ast.literal_eval()` function is not something you should ever really need, generally speaking.